# over function in R not working

Tags: r, sp

I am trying to find the number of pubs for each London LSOA.

I do this with London's LSOA boundaries shapefile which I imported as a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` and a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` of pubs taken from [this website](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) with the following query:

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“pub in london”
*/
[out:json][timeout:30];
// fetch area “london” to search in
{{geocodeArea:london}}->.searchArea;
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “pub”
  node["amenity"="pub"](area.searchArea);
  way["amenity"="pub"](area.searchArea);
  relation["amenity"="pub"](area.searchArea);
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

when I run:

```
result  <- over(pubs, LondonLSOA)
```

Nothing happens. I think I am supposed to get a new column in results but I dont see that.

Can someone advise?

Comment: are they both in the same coordinate reference system?

Comment: What does `summary(pubs)` and `summary(LondonLSOA)` tell you about the coordinates? What about if you `plot(LondonLSOA); plot(pubs, add=TRUE);`? OpenStreetMap works in lat-long degrees and maybe your LSOA is in Ordnance Survey Grid Coordinates? We can't tell without more information.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"? How long did you wait?